# Помогите с удалением одной записи из бд в тг-боте

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, telegram-bot

.кто знаком с инлайн кнопками, прошу помочь. работаю на ноде, бд постгре, уже реализовал вывод всех данных из бд в тг-бот, вот теперь хочу чтобы из всех данных удалился только один запись который выбирает пользователь, но при нажатии кнопки удалить удаляются все данные бд

[image: Визуальная структура реализации...]

```
bot.on('callback_query', query => {
client.query('select * from person_list order by id asc', (err,res) => {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  let jsonString = JSON.stringify(res.rows);
  let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  jsonObj.filter(item => {
    if(query.data === 'delete'){
      client.query(`DELETE FROM person_list WHERE id = ${item.id}`, err =>{
        if(err) throw err;
      })
    }
  });
});
```

});